# python getting dictionary values in lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Been banging my head on desk!
I have an url that is downloaded in json, then parsed_json = json.loads(response_body) to python dictionary. The issue is that data(embedded in dicts is in list) that is needed is in a dictionary called list.  If I do a dict count or key or anything I just get the first level of 3 when there is actually 37 dicts .

```
for key, value in parsed_json.iteritems() :
    print key, value
```

After a week I cannot figure out how to get all values from dicts in the list, I can get one by using something like this but I cannot increment the count.

```
print parsed_json['list'][(1)]['value']
```

This is a digi xbee cloud get, after getting the values there needs to be some math done on some, as the results are in MV's not C degrees.
Any direction to get the values greatly appreciated.

Snippet of data:

```
{u'count': 37,
 u'list': [{u'history_uri': u'/ws/v1/streams/history/00000000-00000000-00409DFF-FF818A13/management/connections',
            u'id': u'00000000-00000000-00409DFF-FF818A13/management/connections',
            u'server_timestamp': u'2015-11-21T04:21:45.407Z',
            u'timestamp': u'2015-11-21T04:21:45.269Z',
            u'type': u'JSON',
            u'value': u'{"connectTime":"2015-11-21T04:21:45.269Z","type":"Ethernet","remoteIp":"72.38.16.255","localIp":"192.168.2.106","session":"17c6e5d2-3d9d-439b-aa8a-36f050bf8b9c"}'},
           {u'history_uri': u'/ws/v1/streams/history/00000000-00000000-00409DFF-FF818A13/xbee.analog/[00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:0A]!/AD1',
            u'id': u'00000000-00000000-00409DFF-FF818A13/xbee.analog/[00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:0A]!/AD1',
            u'server_timestamp': u'2015-11-22T08:14:15.945Z',
            u'timestamp': u'2015-11-22T08:14:09.101Z',
            u'type': u'INTEGER',
            u'value': u'1'},
           {u'history_uri': u'/ws/v1/streams/history/00000000-00000000-00409DFF-FF818A13/xbee.analog/[00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:0A]!/AD2',
            u'id': u'00000000-00000000-00409DFF-FF818A13/xbee.analog/[00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:0A]!/AD2',
            u'server_timestamp': u'2015-11-22T08:14:15.964Z',
            u'timestamp': u'2015-11-22T08:14:09.377Z',
            u'type': u'INTEGER',
            u'value': u'613'},
           {u'history_uri': u'/ws/v1/streams/history/00000000-00000000-00409DFF-FF818A13/xbee.analog/[00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:0A]!/AD3',
            u'id': u'00000000-00000000-00409DFF-FF818A13/xbee.analog/[00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:0A]!/AD3',
            u'server_timestamp': u'2015-11-22T08:14:15.930Z',
            u'timestamp': u'2015-11-22T08:14:08.854Z',
            u'type': u'INTEGER',
            u'value': u'852'},
           {u'history_uri': u'/ws/v1/streams/history/00000000-00000000-00409DFF-FF818A13/xbee.analog/[00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:50]!/AD1',
            u'id': u'00000000-00000000-00409DFF-FF818A13/xbee.analog/[00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:50]!/AD1',
            u'server_timestamp': u'2015-11-22T08:14:15.834Z',
            u'timestamp': u'2015-11-22T08:14:07.477Z',
            u'type': u'INTEGER',
            u'value': u'0'},
           {u'history_uri': u'/ws/v1/streams/history/00000000-00000000-00409DFF-FF818A13/xbee.analog/[00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:50]!/AD2',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
for index in range(parsed_json['count']):
    print(parsed_json['list'][index]['value'])
```

Or simpler:

```
for item in parsed_json['list']:
    print(item['value'])
```

You can print all key-value pairs by iterating over `items()`

```
for entry in parsed_json['list']:
    for key, value in entry.items():
        print(key)
        print('    ', value)
```

In Python 2 write `print '    ', value` because `print` is a function in Python 3 but still a statement in Python 2. If you are new to Python, start with Python 3. Python 2 is the legacy Python.

Comment: thank you
Not sure second one is easier as they are both just two lines, but it is cleaner. And they both work!! Now how do I get multiple data values"fields" using the one print statement? Everything I try so far has not worked, but I'm extremely new to python. Haven't written any code in > 20 years.

Comment: Figured out multiple values, not sure if best way but it works.

print (item['timestamp']), (item['id']), (item['value'])

Comment: You can loop over all dictionary items in each list entry. I added an example.

Comment: @MikeMueller Thank You Mike, Dr. Mueller I think there is an issue with that or the data. If I run both print statements I get 10889 lines with a unique data value repeating 51 times. If I run just the bottom print statement I get 6498 lines with the same unique data value repeating 59 times. If I convert the dict to xml there is 457 lines. I'm new to python but Digi API and ESP(IDE) are based on 2.7 I could email the data file to the academy if you would like.

Comment: Better [upload](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265388/upload-a-mat-file-to-stack-overflow-for-the-purpose-of-illustration) the file somewhere to make it available for all.

Comment: Ok here is the Onedrive link http://1drv.ms/1ObQLXS to the json file with the data.

Comment: ok didn't notice you provided a site to upload to: here is the link http://speedy.sh/WQn7P/out1.json

Comment: Your JSON is broken. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yyqerj4ht2cmi3q/AACXPrRCw_ckG4u99nq1AGIVa?dl=0) is version of the JSON I cleaned by hand and a script that reads and prints its content.

Comment: Thanks again for clarifying the issue, unfortunately that was how I recieved the Web Get json file. Then just did a json(dumps) to create the file I uploaded to the web. I'm stuck working with the broken json as Digi provides it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want one list with all the values in the dicts. If what you meant is something else, let me know so I can give you another answer:

```
lst = []
for dict in parsed_json:
  for key in dict:
      lst.append(dict[key])
```