# python partition getting values

Tags: python, string

Continuation of [Getting a list and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860343/python-getting-dictionary-values-in-lists), Ok got it, now formatting before writing to file or table.
I have tried re, split and partition to massage the data into what I need but I'm unsure which is best for my needs. I still need to match mac address to an external file for user friendly names, or maybe that should be further in program. I need to do math on the values though so still need to match mac address: This is what I have, am I headed in the right direction or did I miss something?

```
    for item in parsed_json['list']:
   # print(item['timestamp']), (item['id']), (item['value'])
  #ts = datetime.datetime.strptime((item['timestamp']), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
  ts = datetime.datetime.strptime((item['timestamp']), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
  sts = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
  delta = sts-ts
  time_diff = str(delta).split('.')[0]
  frmt_ts = datetime.datetime.strftime(ts, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
  frmt_part_id = (item['id']).partition("/[")[2]
  frmt_part2_id = (frmt_part_id).partition("]!/")[0] 
  frmt_part3_id = (frmt_part_id).partition("]!/")[2]



  print frmt_ts, frmt_part2_id, frmt_part3_id, (item['value']), "Time difference is:  ", time_diff
```

Which produces output like:

```
11/27/15 15:18:59 00:13:A2:00:40:B5:8A:35 AD1 419 Time difference is:   0:00:11
11/27/15 15:18:59 00:13:A2:00:40:B5:8A:35 AD2 663 Time difference is:   0:00:11
11/27/15 15:18:59 00:13:A2:00:40:B5:8A:3A AD1 63 Time difference is:   0:00:11
11/27/15 15:18:59 00:13:A2:00:40:B5:8A:3A AD2 641 Time difference is:   0:00:11
11/27/15 15:19:00 00:13:A2:00:40:B5:8A:3B AD1 14 Time difference is:   0:00:11
11/27/15 15:18:59 00:13:A2:00:40:B5:8A:3B AD2 639 Time difference is:   0:00:11
11/27/15 15:19:00 00:13:A2:00:40:B7:AE:D6 AD1 4 Time difference is:   0:00:10
11/27/15 15:19:00 00:13:A2:00:40:B7:AE:D6 AD2 618 Time difference is:   0:00:11
11/26/15 13:51:58 00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:0A AD1 10 Time difference is:   1 day, 1:27:12
11/26/15 13:51:58 00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:0A AD2 685 Time difference is:   1 day, 1:27:12
11/26/15 13:51:58 00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:0A AD3 853 Time difference is:   1 day, 1:27:12
11/26/15 18:30:28 00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:50 AD1 2 Time difference is:   20:48:42
11/26/15 18:30:29 00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:50 AD2 712 Time difference is:   20:48:42
11/26/15 18:30:28 00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:50 AD3 13 Time difference is:   20:48:42
11/27/15 15:19:01 00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:5B AD1 28 Time difference is:   0:00:10
11/27/15 15:19:01 00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:5B AD2 602 Time difference is:   0:00:09
11/27/15 15:19:00 00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:5B AD3 445 Time difference is:   0:00:10
11/27/15 13:35:35 00:13:A2:00:40:D5:8F:6F AD1 7 Time difference is:   1:43:35
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

mac_re = re.compile(r'([\dA-F]{2}:){7}[\dA-F]{2}', re.I) # use re.I or not, case-sensitive
processed_items = []
for item in parsed_json['list']:
    processed_item = {}
    # do some process, you should consider exceptions
    _s = mac_re.search(item.get('id', ''))
    processed_item['mac'] = _s.group() if _s else ''
    processed_item['value'] = item.get('value')
    # append the processed_item
    processed_items.append(processed_item)
# do some other process with those processed_items
```

### =========some explanation=========

`([\dA-F]{2}:){7}[\dA-F]{2}` this is a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

- `\d` matches a single number `0-9`
- `A-F` matches a single character from `A` to `F`
- `[\dA-F]` matches a single character, which could be `0-9` or `A-F`
- `[\dA-F]{2}` matches twice
- `([\dA-F]{2}:){7}` matches `[\dA-F]{2}` 7 times

So, `([\dA-F]{2}:){7}[\dA-F]{2}` this matches a mac address presented in string

the `re.I` flag set ignoring the case, means `A` can matches `a`

Comment: Thank You, But I really don't understand. I found what the dA means but not the -F, take two digits separated by colon 7 times. You can get value as it is a standalone data point. Don't understand _s or group. MAC address is not unique in itself it also needs the AD1,2,3 to separate each reading. I did spend a couple of hours trying your way but short term memory is nonexistent, so it flew over my head.

Comment: I add some explanation. `_s.group()` get the matching result(mac)

Comment: Thank You for the great explanation, it was an aha moment. I Thought the \A was the flag "Matches only at the start of the string". How would I change your provided snippet to include the text beyond the !/ eg; DIO11 or AD2. I did look and experiment but failed.